# I am having an error installing vlc, below is the output i get when i type sudo apt install vlc

Tags: vlc

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 3.0.9.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy vlc vlc-plugin-base curl` to the question by editing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

or

go to the ubuntu store and then search ***vlc***  and then selet the vlc media player and click install beside it .

if all ways doesnt work then check then checkout the system requirement

I hope I solved your problem

//

Thankyou

Keval Shah

Comment: still showing the same error

Comment: I think re-install apt and snap and try again